# SQLite data lost between Simulator App launches

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-simulator, xcode7

This feels strange and I somehow could not find an answer through search. This is an issue on Xcode iOS Simulator.

I am write an data persistence code. When instantiate the data store, I pretty much copied the following code fragment from Apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH4-SW1).

Now, the issue seems - storeURL (when in debugging) is a URL containing a long numeric string and when relaunching the simulator, that long numeric string was changed. So the sqlite file is not reachable any more. I do believe I saved the data correctly because I debugged through the code (and context save api called with no error), I retrieved data after saving (without relaunching) and I see the data using command line sqlite tool against the sqlite file.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class DataController: NSObject {
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    init() {
        // This resource is the same name as your xcdatamodeld contained in your project.
        guard let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("DataModel", withExtension:"momd") else {
            fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
        }
        // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL) else {
            fatalError("Error initializing mom from: \(modelURL)")
        }
        let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)
        self.managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
        self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
            let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
            let docURL = urls[urls.endIndex-1]
            /* The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file.
            This code uses a file named "DataModel.sqlite" in the application's documents directory.
            */
            let storeURL = docURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("DataModel.sqlite")
            do {
                try psc.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: nil)
            } catch {
                fatalError("Error migrating store: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of copying Mac code and trying to use it on iOS, do this: when you create your iOS project, check the Core Data checkbox. This gives you the correct template code up front.

Comment: Thank you Matt. Yes. That solved the issue.

Comment: Cool. I figured you were probably making some mistake in the code, but I was too lazy to hunt for it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what basically Matt said in the comment section. This issue is related to where to place the .sqlite file.